# Implementation of n-ary trees in c

Tags: c, tree

Can someone please tell me what the 2-D array in n-ary tree is exactly used for?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int row = 5;//no. of input lines
            //1st element in each row is node Value, 2nd - no of child, ,>=3rd....=>value of child
    int data[5][6];
    int i,j,k,m;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter value of Node:\t");
        for(j=0;j<6;j++)
        {
            if(j==1)
                printf("\nEnter no of child:\t");
            else if(j==2)
                printf("\nEnter Values of child\n(if child not present enter 0 as value):\t");
                scanf("%d",&data[i][j]);
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like the n-array tree you're talking about is represented by an 2d array. its used as the underline data structure to store data.

Comment: Yeah but what I am not getting is how it is used.Here is the complete code

Comment: This is true for each row [total 5 rows where i is the numeric row order ]
data[i][1] is the node value
data[i][2] is the number of children of this node
data[i][3] value of 1st child
data[i][4] value of 2st child
data[i][5] value of 3st child...data[i][6] value of 4st child
if data [i][2] is 1 then we only have valid value in data[i][3] but no values in data[i][4], data[i][5] and data[i][6]